# Como fazer alerta de conexão?

Tags: ajax, conexão, alertdialog

bom eu sou iniciante em ajax e queria saber como que eu posso fazer uma verificação de conexão com a internet, e exibir mensagem na tela caso tenha ou não uma conexão ativa com à internet (imagino que isso seja possível com Ajax, mas ainda não achei nada satisfatório na internet).

Segue abaixo imagens exemplos do que eu quero fazer:

[image: alerta de conexão yahoo]

Fonte: yahoo.com

[image: alerla de conexao olx]
Fonte: olx.com.br

Desde já agradeço qualquer contribuição!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando voce clicar no botão poderá fazer isso

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log('online'); //mas voce coloca seu algoritmo
} else {
  console.log('offline');
}
```

fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

**Não funciona no opera**, no caso você teria que fazer um request com Ajax para o seu pŕoprio website, se a requisição falhar, as chances que não tem internet são grandes.

Comment: Paid'égua mano!...Muito bom mesmo, e simples!

Comment: Valeu a ajuda, deu certinho aqui!...(A questão do ópera não ser compatível acredito que não vá trazer grandes problemas)

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser testar a conexão de forma geral você pode usar `navigator.onLine`. Já se você quiser colocar um tempo limite nas suas chamadas AJAX você pode usar o parâmetro `timeout` (se estiver usando Jquary) que aceita um número que é o tempo em milissegundos que a função deve esperar um retorno. Apos isso, é lançado uma exceção. Segue um exemplo de como usar:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    method: 'post',
    dataType:"json",
    timeout: 60000,
    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
        if(exception == 'timeout'){
            alert('Tempo limite de 6 segundos foi ultrapassado');
        }
    }
});
```